# undefined local variable or method `acts_as_gmappable'

Tags: google-maps, gmaps4rails

I created a Heroku app which utilizes the gmaps4fails gem for one of the application's features.

When I tried to seed the database, I get

`rake aborted! 
undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_gmappable' for #<Class:0x00000004b5b928>`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Everything works fine when testing locally.

Edit: Here's my model code

```
    class Hall < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :hall_features
      has_many :green_features, :through => :hall_features
      has_many :settings, :through => :pinned_halls
      belongs_to :operational_unit

      acts_as_gmappable
      ...
```

Migration:

```
class CreateHalls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table 'halls' do |t|
      t.string 'name'
      t.text 'background'
      t.text 'energy_info'
      t.float 'latitude'
      t.float 'longitude'
      t.boolean 'gmaps'
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'halls' # deletes the whole table and all its data!
  end
end
```

Here's the error from my terminal: http://i48.tinypic.com/zvoggg.png

Comment: did you bundle + reload your server?

Comment: I did 'bundle install' and 'bundle update' multiple times while trying to get it to work.

Been trying 'heroku run rake db:migrate' (which goes through fine)
'heroku restart' to restart processes 
'heroku run rake db:seed' which gives the same error again. 

Been at this for a couple hours already. Hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh .. put the gem under :development in Gemfile only. Including it in :production solved everything.

I'll be crying myself to sleep tonight. Some tears of happiness too.